# centering in browser window, works in safari but not firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, centering

I need a popup window to be centered in the browser window regardless of where the page is scrolled to. The window function is with jquery. This works in Safari but not in other browsers:

```
#infoBox1, #infoBox2, #infoBox3, #infoBox4 {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15% -35% 0 -35%;
    z-index: 400;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: left: 0; right; 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 15%;

Answer (score 0):

You can center the element using :

```
 .div { 
    position:absolute; // or use fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, 
Hope this help

```
#infoBox1, #infoBox2, #infoBox3, #infoBox4 {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 400;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
#infoBox1, #infoBox2, #infoBox3, #infoBox4 {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 400;
}
```

`transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` will make sure the `left 50%` and `top 50%` will be taken from the inside of the selected div, not just the outside making it more to the left/top then you expect it to be.